# How to filter part with RegExp

Tags: regex

I want to get all bloc which begin with "- " and not begin with "- ERROR" and "- FAILED"

Here is my regex:

```
^- .*(?:\r?\n(?!- ).*)*
```

### Demo at Regex101

Comment: Add TEST to the pattern and ERROR and FAILED to the negative lookahead `^- TEST.*(?:\r?\n(?!- (?:ERROR|FAILED)).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/ua4KZJ/1 Can you add the pattern to the question?

Comment: Sorry, i make a mistake in my description. i want all bloc begin with " - "  
except  blocs "- ERROR" and "- FAILED"

Comment: Like this `^- TEST.*(?:\r?\n(?!- (?:TEST|ERROR|FAILED)).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/2nxAoQ/1

Comment: Thank you but i want to get all block not necessary begin with - TEST. Is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead for the first assertion matching not ERROR or FAILED and match all the next lines that do not start with `-` and a space to get the separate blocks:

```
^- (?!ERROR|FAILED).*(?:\r?\n(?!- ).*)*
```

The pattern will now match:

- `^` Start of string
- `-`  Match `-` and a space
- `(?!ERROR|FAILED).*` Assert what is directly to the right is not ERROR or FAILED
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!- ).*` Match a newline, assert not `-` and a space at the start and match any char 0+ times
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xwDT8Y/1)

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern seems to be working, at least using your demo tool:

```
- TEST\b.*?(?=- (?:ERROR|TEST|FAILED)|$)
```

### Demo

The pattern says to:

```
- TEST\b                       match "- TEST" followed by a word boundary
.*?                            then match all content up until looking ahead and seeing
(?=- (?:ERROR|TEST|FAILED)|$)  the start of another block with ERROR, TEST, or FAILED
```

Note that I am using dot all mode, and also I have turned off `^` and `$` anchors, such that they mean the start and end of the entire input (and not of every single line).